# Why did the HTTP protocol was designed as request-respose? and how is it affecting the security of web applications?

Tags: security, http, httpwebrequest, protocols, layer

I was reading about the HTTP protocol  - the request - response and how it works.
there are two things that I'm still not sure I undersand and would love to get some explanations
first, is why the HTTP protocol was designed as request-response? what are the benefits of it? or were there other options?
and the second is how does this protocol affects the security of web applications? I know that https is more secure because it is using encryption..but does it mean that http is not secure at all? (even if I'm using POST and not GET etc..)

thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know HTTP was primarily designed to fetch and read documents. It is not the best protocol for a far interaction, but it is good to tell the HTTP Server which document you want to have and to receive it. And that's just how the Internet began - a large number of documents that should be accessible to anyone. The development started in 1989 at CERN, sharing science and university documents was the primary task.

The only benefit you gain from HTTPS is that your request and your response both are encrypted. That means, that no one except for the client and the server should be able to know what both communicated about. But as I am currently developing an HTTP client I can't see any security benefits from POST in opposite to GET (except, of course, that some client-side scripts (javascript) may not have access to the request content).

All in all, HTTP is not the best protocol for websites in general I think, but it is good to support a wide range of features - because with HTTP you can implement static documents as well as the most complex and dynamic websites.

/EDIT

I don't think that HTTP is unsafe at all. Well, in which case should it be unsafe? There is only the possibility for some software to know which resource was requested with which parameters, but wether or not that is a problem for you: Any other protocol (except for encrypted ones) faces the same problem.

Also, as the HTTP 1.1 standard was published in 1999, they are finally working on a new version called HTTP 2.0 that is (according to the RFC from November 2012) almost a copy from Google's SPDY (pronounced speedy) protocol that is way faster than HTTP 1.1.

Unfortunately, I am unable to find the demonstration page launched by Google, but the new protocol is way faster especially when loading many small resources (like icons).

Comment: thank you ! so is there any impact on web apps security? if it is an unsafe protocol why is being used?

Comment: I improved the answer: I don't see why it should be more unsafe than any over protocol, do you?

Comment: thank you, I'm still a little confused why the protocol was chosen to be request-response  - it's kinnda synchronic.. why not doing it a-sync? or using another method?

Comment: You have to take into account HTTP's long history. In the early days of the Internet, websites were very basic and a  request/response model was more than sufficient for them. The first version of HTTP did not even have headers to describe the request/response data being exchanged. That model has been maintained through the years (just with the addition of headers, encryption, and other optimizations). There have been proposals to add asynchronous handling to HTTP (pipelining, etc), but they are largely still unused. SPDY, HTTP 2.0, etc are next-gen protocols to replace synchronous HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

The are many issues you should care if you want to develop a secured Web application.
It related both to HTTP 1.x and 2.x.
Please find below the example of security problem should be carried in your application:
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project